# IF function with multiple criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to use an IF function to return a "1" if TRUE and a "0" if FALSE.

I need cell A1 or B1 AND C1 > 0  in order for the statement to be TRUE (return `1`), else FALSE (return `0`).

I cannot write the function correctly.

Comment: Look into nested IF functions.

Comment: You need to make your question more clear. (A1 > 0 OR B1 > 0) AND C1 > 0 is not the same thing as  A1 > 0 OR (B1 > 0 AND C1 > 0)

Comment: Perhaps also look into BEDMAS (Order of Operations).

Answer (score 1):

one way is compound use of and() and or() inside an IF statement.

```
=IF(AND(OR(A1>0,B1>0),C1>0),1,0)
```

The or() is evauluated first, then and() with the result, and the result of that is then the basis for the `condition` clause of the if() statement.

Answer (score 1):

I'm only keying off of your capitalization of your "or" and "AND" here, assuming you mean:

(A1 > 0 Or B1 > 0) AND C1 > 0

```
=IF(AND(OR(A1>0,B1>0),C1>0),1,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Your Question**

Your question is a special case because the output you want is `1` or `0`.  You don't actually need an IF statement to do this; Excel treats true and false values as `1` and `0`.  You don't even need AND or OR.  It's referred to as Boolean logic.

I'll start with the solution that Tyson and panhandel posted (note EBGreen's and TECHIE007's comments about the order of operations and adjust the formula if your intent was different).

If you remove the IF function, you get:

```
=AND(OR(A1>0,B1>0),C1>0)
```

If you use that in a calculation, it will be treated as `1` if true or `0` if false.  In this form, it will display in the cell as TRUE or FALSE.  If you want to make it display as `1` or `0`, just use it in a calculation that doesn't change its value:

```
=AND(OR(A1>0,B1>0),C1>0)+0
```

---

**Just for Interest**

So how do you eliminate the AND and OR?  Each component comparison is true or false, so you can take advantage of basic math using zeros and ones.  If two things must be true (the AND case), use:

```
1 * 1 = 1  (both true)
1 * 0 = 0  (one true, one false)
0 * 0 = 0  (both false)
```

Any combination other than two ones will result in 0.

The OR situation can be expressed in reverse.

```
A=true OR B=true
```

is the same as

```
NOT( A=false AND B=false )
```

So you can express OR as AND.  You create the NOT, using `1 - result`.

So, your expression can be in the form:

```
=(1-(A1<=0)*(B1<=0))*(C1>0)
```

No IFs, ANDs, or ORs.